# sorting a field of datatable which have special character

Tags: c#, sorting, datatables

I have a `datatable` which have some columns which I have populated from a table in a access database. One special column that I have is SN which consists data like this:

```
SN
_____
-1
1.a
1.a
1.b
10
1000
1001
1002
11.a
11.b
13.a
2.a
2.b
2.c
2000
2001
21.a
22.b
3.a
3.b
3.c
4000
4001
4.a
```

The SN field is in string format and when I sort the data the result is as shown above.
But what I like to have here is the sorted column which I am hoping to be something like this:

```
 SN
_____
-1
1.a
1.a
1.b
2.a
2.b
2.c
3.a
3.b
3.c
4.a
10
11.a
11.b
13.a
21.a
22.b
1000
1001
1002
2000
2001
4000
4001
```

What can be done to achieve this?

**UPDATE:** I have added nore data for clarity. The result I acquired after implementing the suggested code is:

```
SN
_____
-1
1.a
1.a
1.b
10
11.a
11.b
13.a
2.a
2.b
2.c
21.a
22.b
3.a
3.b
3.c
4.a
1000
1001
1002
2000
2001
4000
4001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort your datatable using enumarable features. It's a bit painful but could you try the code below ?

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
myDataTable.Columns.Add("SN", typeof(string));
//string myValues = "-1;1.a;1.b;10;1000;1001;1002;2.c;2.b;2.a;2000;2001;3.a;3.b;3.c;4000;4001;4.a;1.a";
string myValues = "a;a.b;c.c;-1;1.a;1.a;1.b;10;11.a;11.b;13.a;2.a;2.b;2.c;21.a;22.b;3.a;3.b;3.c;4.a;1000;1001;1002;2000;2001;4000;4001";
string[] myValuesArray = myValues.Split(';');

foreach (string myValue in myValuesArray)
{
    DataRow myRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
    myRow["SN"] = myValue;
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(myRow);
}

string beforeSort = string.Join(";", myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["SN"]));
Console.WriteLine("Before Sorting:");
Console.WriteLine(beforeSort);

IEnumerable<DataRow> sortedValues = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                    .OrderBy(x =>
                                    {
                                        string currentStringValue = x["SN"].ToString();
                                        string[] currentStringValueArray = currentStringValue.Split('.');

                                        if (currentStringValueArray.Length == 2)
                                        {
                                            string currentPart = "";
                                            int currentPartNumeric = 0;
                                            if (int.TryParse(currentStringValueArray[0], out currentPartNumeric))
                                            {
                                                currentPart += currentPartNumeric.ToString();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                //We are assuming our alphanumeric chars are integers
                                                currentPart += (((int)(char.ToUpper(char.Parse(currentStringValueArray[0])))) - 64).ToString();
                                            }

                                            if (int.TryParse(currentStringValueArray[1], out currentPartNumeric))
                                            {
                                                currentPart += "." + currentPartNumeric.ToString();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                //We are assuming our alphanumeric chars are integers
                                                currentPart += "." + (((int)(char.ToUpper(char.Parse(currentStringValueArray[1])))) - 64).ToString();
                                            }
                                            return Convert.ToDecimal(currentPart, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                        }
                                        else if (currentStringValueArray.Length == 1)
                                        {
                                            int currentPartNumeric = 0;
                                            string currentPart = "";
                                            if (int.TryParse(currentStringValueArray[0], out currentPartNumeric))
                                            {
                                                currentPart += currentPartNumeric.ToString();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                //We are assuming our alphanumeric chars are integers
                                                currentPart += "." + (((int)(char.ToUpper(char.Parse(currentStringValueArray[0])))) - 64).ToString();
                                            }
                                            return Convert.ToDecimal(currentPart, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                        }
                                        else
                                            return 0m;
                                    });

string afterSort = string.Join(";", sortedValues.Select(x => x["SN"]));
Console.WriteLine("After Sorting:");
Console.WriteLine(afterSort);

//Copy to your existing datatable
myDataTable = sortedValues.CopyToDataTable();
```

PS: I mixed your existing data due being sure about the code stability

Update: This is just an example to your data, please keep in mind you should modify the OrderBy scope according to your data diversity. That example will work only for x.y and x format of data.

Hope this helps

Comment: Although your code is fabulous, it didn't work as expected. Above show is just a some samples of the datatable. The result after applying your code was: `-1, 1.a, 1.b, 11.a,12.a, 13.a, 2.a, 2.b and so on`

Comment: @Skaranjit so I get it and updated my answer can you check it ?